# How do Pizza Delivery Websites determine if you are in their delivery area?

Tags: maps

I wondered how Pizza Delivery websites manage to determine if your adress in the delivery area of the store, most stores only deliver within a distance of 5km, does the website estimate the distance between your adress and the stores address or how do they do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are several services which already provide the functionality. You just need to type two addresses there and you will get distance between two points([Example](https://www.mapdevelopers.com/distance_from_to.php?&from=%20One%205th%20Ave%2C%20New%20York&to=61%20W%208th%20St%2C%20New%20York)). 
[image]

Developers of the delivery apps just use the API and than checks whether or not the distance exceeds the possible delivery distance.

All you need to do is to make user provide valid addresses(via form validation) which will be accepted by these services.

Comment: OK, do you know where I can use a API like that? Google Maps API maybe?

Comment: I think you can use google maps api as well as writing your own api for working with the site I linked.

Comment: I dont know if the site likes me making multiple thousand requests a day.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, the site uses google maps api internally. Google maps is more reliable, though.

Comment: cant I just use the gmaps API myself? Which one is it?

Comment: Of course you can use just google maps api. There are several question already about it on SO, just google it. They use [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/#DistanceMatrixRequests)

Comment: ehm. Ok so it doesnt work that way. These pizza delivery websites have multiple thousand stores, i dont think they make thousands of request every time someone enters their adress.